# Reading till the end of a line in C++

Tags: c++, file

I have a text file like this :

> Sting Another string  0 12 0 5 3 8
>  
>   Sting Another string  8 13 2 0 6 11

And I want to count how many numbers are there. I think my best bet is to use while type cycle with a condition to end counting then another line starts but I do not know how to stop reading at the end of a line.

Thanks for your help in advance ;)

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Split your `input` stream into lines

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(input, line))
{
  // process each line here
}
```

To split a line into words, use a stringstream:

```
std::istringstream linestream(line); // #include <sstream>
std::string word;
while (linestream >> word)
{
  // process word
}
```

You can repeat this for each word to decide whether it contains a number. Since you didn't specify whether your numbers are integer or non-integers, I assume `int`:

```
std::istringstream wordstream(word);
int number;
if (wordstream >> number)
{
  // process the number (count, store or whatever)
}
```

Disclaimer: This approach is not perfect. It will detect "numbers" at the beginning of words like `123abc`, it will also allow an input format like `string 123 string`. Also this approach is not very efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use a `getline()`?

Answer (score 1):

End of Line is represented by '\n' character.
Put a condition in your while loop to end when it encounters '\n'